# unix diff command question

Tags: unix, command

I got two files. I want to use diff to compare those to see what has been changed.
I checked man diff but there are log of options. Could anyone give me a quick hint what should I do?
thank you you all!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ diff -u module.erl.orig module.erl.new
```

will give you a differences between files in unified form. You can also save them to a file

```
$ diff -u module.erl.orig module.erl.new > module.erl.patch
```

And patch an original file to have these changes:

```
$ patch -p module.erl.orig < module.erl.patch
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple: `diff path/to/file1 path/to/file2`